How would I go about making a Roblox friend chain finder without getting Rate Limited?
How would I make a Roblox friend chain finder (Finding someone who is friends with a friend who is friends with someone and so on) using Roblox API without getting rate limited. I do also want to make sure it doesn’t take forever.
I have tried making a cooldown when I get rate limited
   elif response.status_code == 429: 
            print('Rate limit hit. Pausing...')
            time.sleep(backoff_time)
            backoff_time = min(backoff_time * 2, max_backoff) 

However when I tried using this solution it will most likely take more than 20-40 minutes trying to find the specific user. I have also tried finding examples from users but I couldn’t find anything related to this topic. I would really appreciate the help!

If you asking if their is a way for you to trick their API, the answer is probably no. I'm not saying it's impossible. I'm saying it isn't likely. Your likely only bet to eliminate rate limiting is to stop using the API altogether and find a way to scrape the data. Or possibly use a combination. Only use the API to discover the hardest information to acquire, and use basic web scraping for the rest of it.
